# Subversion deployment workflow for webdevelopment

Tags: svn, deployment, web-deployment

Im still learning the basics of subversion but since the beginning i had a goal to achieve with this cvs: automating the site deployment process.

Is there any solution to automate the process of site updates to the webserver?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208484/how-to-best-update-a-website-from-subversion

Answer (score 3):

If you checkout the code to the server you can create a post-commit hook that automatically updates that working copy when a commit is made. This is probably only useful if you have a separate branch just for deployment, that you merge into the code that is ready for deployment.

[Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#website-auto-update)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script a while ago to do exactly what you want for Windows.

It does assume that you are pushing across a network share and that you are wanting some work flow like Developer -> Source Control -> Dev Server.

[Publishing Subversion Repositories using Windows XP/2000/2003](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Subversion.aspx#9.0)

Comment: Thanks Ralph, i will try this. Have you considered something like Fabric to automate the deployment process?

Comment: I've had quick look at Fabric (http://fabfile.org) and I like the idea. I currently use NAnt + NAntContrib as they contain all the functionality I need for deployment