# Where to store users' content? (SVN and PHP)

Tags: php, svn, git, codeigniter

For example, we have the web-site written using popular PHP-framework and we continue developing it, adding new features etc. Users fill up content by themselves (this creates new records in a database and new files (avatars, images, media) uploaded to the *production*).

So, let's imagine that we've renewed our site (added features, corrected some bugs) and decided to run `svn update` in the *production*. What will we have then? Will the files uploaded by users been removed? (because they, of course, don't exist in the repository)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208484/how-to-best-update-a-website-from-subversion Please check this on using 'svn export' vs 'svn update' in production environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as they haven't got the same names as files that are in the repository, SVN will ignore them and not touch them.

Answer (score 1):

No, a svn update will only affect versioned files.